# Get user id from username Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make a program that will get the user id of a username you enter.
Here is what I have so far:

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(description="a", command_prefix=".", self_bot = False)

client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    user = await client.fetch_user("pirace#4637")
    print(user)

client.run('token')
```

It gives me this error:

```
400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In user_id: Value "pirace#4637" is not snowflake.
```

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: You've exposed your bot token. Please edit your post to remove it and you should reset it on the discord developer dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch_user` takes in a snowflake or in easier terms, id. Getting a user with usernername is possible by making something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx, user:discord.User):
    return await ctx.send(user.name)
```

This only works if the user shares a guild with your bot though and is case sensitive. So either put a valid user id as an integer in `bot.fetch_user` or use the code I provided

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the name of the user you have to use [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get), in this case combined with [`client.get_guild(GUILD_ID)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild).

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(description="a", command_prefix=".", self_bot = False)

client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = client.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
    
    user = discord.utils.get(guild.members, name="pirace", discriminator="4637")

    print(user)

client.run('token')
```